# grep selectively

Tags: grep

I have a file of 1000+ designators that from bash I use

```
for desig in $(desfile)
do
  grep $desig in listfile
done
```

listfile can every 1 million + lines, so speed is important

The problem is for designators like

```
PA0EHH
DL/PA0EHH
```

that `PA0EHH` is found twice

I found that awk could be more selective but is painfully slow.

Comment: Which one do you want it to show?

Comment: Is `desfile` a command?

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -xF -f desfile listfile
```

Or, if `desfile` is a command,

```
grep -xF -f <(desfile) listfile
```

or,

```
desfile | grep -xF -f /dev/stdin listfile
```

The options used here are

- `-x`, requires a match across the whole length of the a line.  This is what you want to use to not match substrings on lines.
- `-F`, uses string comparisons rather than regular expression matching.  This will speed up the query, and would be necessary if your patterns contain characters that are special in regular expressions (without you wanting them to be special).
- `-f filename`, read the patterns from a file rather than from strings on the command line.  This will work for a moderate amount of patterns. If you have many *many* patterns, you may run out of memory, in which case you may want to split `desfile` (or the output of `desfile` if it's a command) into several smaller files using `split` and then iterate over these.  In any case, you would *not* want to call `grep` once for each pattern!

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for your designator being the beginning of each row you could

```
grep ^$desig listfile
```

If you want to limit it to the first hit, add switch `-m 1`.
If you need a more fine grained search try regex:

```
testval=2
seq 40 | grep -e ^$testval\\b
seq 40 | grep -e \\b$testval\\b
```

both match exactly 2, depending on your usecase.
And to prevent grep from recognizing e.g. `2/2`

```
echo "2/2 2" | grep -e [^\/]\\b$testval\\b
```

colors in my bash only the lonely 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since performance is a concern, considering using `ripgrep`, which benchmarks faster than `grep` for a number of cases.